# Is it possible to run a react app that already has been assigned a domain name, locally?

Tags: reactjs, web-development-server

I have a React application which is currently running in a server under a particular Domain name. I want to develop it further and hence copied the entire directory into my local system using ssh command. After installing all the dependencies using npm install, and then on trying to start the app; my entire system is hanging. Thinking that there might be something wrong with my system, I tried and successfully ran another React SPA from my local system. I am relatively new to React and CS in general so could anyone give any explanation as to why this is happening?

Comment: Are the project not on GitHub?

Comment: It might be depending on some ENV variables. But other than that i cant think of why u cant run it locally

Comment: Did you download the source code or the built version? Since you could run npm install my guess would be you downloaded the source code but then why was it on the server?

Comment: By server do you mean a hosting site?

Comment: yes. the project is on Github. In my local system I tried cloning it, still didn't run. I think @kevin is right and it must have some ENV variable dependencies. Yes the traditional server is the hosting site. The React app is running just fine on the said hosting site and I copied the entire code from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webpack < 5 was used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. Maybe this was the reason for the code not compiling.